# How to store a large number of keys/codes in a database. DJANGO

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

Let me explain. I've built a website using python, django. One of the issues i've run into now is i'm not sure how i should go about this. Every user on the website will be uploading a LARGE amount of basically keys/codes onto the website which will be linked to their accounts. It will be in the thousands per user.
I'd imagine having a row for every single key/code is not efficient at all. Is there maybe any way to store lists or something similar? If i have a row per code/key after only 100 users it would be up in the hundreds of thousands rows.

Comment: You are expecting every user to be storing thousands of these keys?

Comment: @Abion47 Yes correct. The purpose of the website will have them store thousands of these keys.

Comment: Well it depends on what you want to be able to do with them. If all you want to do is store them, PostgreSQL has an [array data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html). However, if you're going to want to view them, sort them, query against them, or do modifications to them after insertion, then all the efficiency you may or may not save in storage space will get replaced by just as much if not more complexity in processing time. My recommendation is to not overthink this and keep it simple. Use rows and only look at optimization if and when you _know_  it is a problem.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with putting lots of data in a table, thats what they're for. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases run fine with millions of records and lookups. 
In my experiance Postgresql had some problem with bulk updates 
(10000s of records from millions updated with a single query was little slow.)

You can use this kind of model

```
from django.db import models

class UserData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

or You can use a Table with JSONField

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models

class UserData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = JSONField()
```

You will get a JSON object for time you query it, and work with it like a dictionary in views and update back with the db.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there's nothing wrong with having hundreds of thousands of rows, that's what RDBMSes are good for!

```
class Code(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=..., unique=True)
```

is a perfectly fine model for this. You can then access an user's codes via the reverse manager `user.code_set`.

- If you don't want codes to be globally unique in your system, remove the `unique=True` constraint
- If you want codes to be unique per user, add `class Meta: unique_together = (('user', 'code'),)`